# 301 redirect .htaccess all traffic to specific domain and uri

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am lost... as always the htaccess file is like vodoo...
i am trying to redirect all traffic from a domain regardless of its URI to a specific page on another domain. This is what I have and it is failing with a 500 error:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.) domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/some/other/page/ [L,R=301]
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Like I said I am trying to ignore the URI requested and force a redirect to a specicif page on another domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect *everything* from `domain.com` (and also every subdomains), try this way

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.example.com/some/other/page/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ok so it works beautifully with the domain by its self but none of the subdomains work, they get a 500 error

Comment: Strange. What was/were the url(s) you tried with subdomains ?

Comment: I cannot give those out for confidentiality, but they are www.domain.com and a few others all of them are pointing correctly (using dns and vhost info) and have been verified to be doing so.

Comment: Really weird. I don't think this is a problem in my code but from your server side. Could you try again with this new code ? If this last one does not work, this probably means there is another problem

Comment: That worked this time, I am thinking my .htaccess was not overwriting correctly because this time i deleted it and reuploaded a new copy and now it works. Thank you!